# Using a bounded generic class to extend another generic class produces an unknown type

Tags: java, generics

So imagine the following class hierarchy:

```
abstract class Train {}
class BulletTrain extends Train {}

abstract class Base<T> {}
abstract class TrainBuilder<T extends Train> extends Base<T> {}

class BulletTrainBuilder<T extends BulletTrain> extends TrainBuilder<T> {
    T getBulletTrain() {
        BulletTrain someBulletTrain;
        // Make some kind of BulletTrain and put it in someBulletTrain
        return someBulletTrain; // Compile Error: BulletTrain does not match T
    }
}
```

Inside `getBulletTrain`, it seems that no subclass of `BulletTrain`, or `BulletTrain` instance can be returned, as Java makes a compile error which states that the particular subclass (or BulletTrain itself) does not match `T`.

Has type information been lost somehow here?

Comment: T getBulletTrain should be    BulletTrain getBulletTrain , as you are only sure you are returning BulletTrain, not the specific subclass you  have in T.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type information hasn't been lost, it's just that from `BulletTrainBuilder` you can't determine that `T` is `BulletTrain` and not some subclass of it.

For example, what if I did this:

```
BulletTrainBuilder<FastBulletTrain> builder = ... ;
```

Calling `getBulletTrain` would try to cast a `BulletTrain` in to a `FastBulletTrain` and throw an exception.

It seems like you just want to do this:

```
class BulletTrainBuilder extends TrainBuilder<BulletTrain> {
    public BulletTrain getBulletTrain() { ... }
}
```

Otherwise, if you need to further delegate `T` down the hierarchy, then you can't know what it is to do something like you're trying to do. You would need to also delegate wherever `someBulletTrain` comes from to the subclass as well.

For example:

```
abstract class AbstractTrainFactory<T extends Train> {
    protected abstract T newTrainInstance();
    public abstract T fashionTrainToSpec();
}

abstract class AbstractBulletTrainFactory<T extends BulletTrain>
extends AbstractTrainFactory<T> {
    @Override
    public T fashionTrainToSpec() {
        T theTrain = newTrainInstance();
        theTrain.noseSwoop = noseSwoopSpec;
        return theTrain;
    }
}

class FastBulletTrainFactory
extends AbstractBulletTrainFactory<FastBulletTrain> {
    @Override
    protected FastBulletTrain newTrainInstance() {
        return new FastBulletTrain();
    }
}
```